# Open the extension's options.html page in new tab when clicking on extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know it's possible to show a popup when clicking on the extension icon (top right of the browser, to the right of the address bar): [`chrome.browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)

[image]

Also [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) is how to create an Options page, that will often have an URL like:

```
chrome-extension://ofodsfyizzsaaahskdhfsdffffdsf/options.html
```

**Question: how is it possible to make that a single click on the extension icon opens the options.html page in a new tab?**

Comment: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(()=>{chrome.tabs.create({url:'options.html'})});`. For this to work, browserAction must **not** have an associated popup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this in your [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages):

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:''});  //disable browserAction's popup

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(()=>{
    chrome.tabs.create({url:'options.html'});
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
...
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Options"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
}
...
```

Comment: In background script.

Comment: Set only the icon(s), but not the popup.

Comment: Strictly speaking `setPopup` should not be needed if `default_popup` wasn't ever set.

Comment: @Xan True. I put it just in case, since the original manifest was not posted with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Manifest v3:

in the `manifest.json`, add an empty action prop to be able to access `chrome.action`:

```
"action": {}
```

you can find more configurations in this [document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/).

Important notice: after the change in manifest, you will have to restart the browser for the "Load unpacked" to take effect.

in the background / service worker file, add a listener of click on extension icon event:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(() => console.log("debug: options page opened"));
});
```